# Get count of selected files in dropzone

Tags: javascript, arrays, dropzone.js

What I m trying to do is get a count of selected files in dropzone before upload them.

```
var count= myDropzoneNST.getAcceptedFiles().length;
```

I can get a count of uploaded files using this line, but What I m trying to do is to get count of selected valid files before upload them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var count= myDropzoneNST.files.length;
```

will give you the total number of files in your dropzone.

Answer (score 19):

```
// To access all files count
myDropzone.files.length
// To access only accepted files count
myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length
// To access all rejected files count
myDropzone.getRejectedFiles().length
// To access all queued files count
myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length
// To access all uploading files count
myDropzone.getUploadingFiles().length
```

Get from document API [here](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/methods)

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the `.get*Files()` methods are not very accurate. The `.getAcceptedFiles().length` usage will return the current number of accepted files minus the one just having been added, if you call it from the `addedFile()` event handler, for example. This may be "as designed", but it makes the wording of "addedFile()" somewhat odd.