# Dropzone Js, find out how many files are currently inside the dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

Im using the dropzone js (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload files but I need to know how many files are currently inside the Dropzone, the user might have deleted some but I need to know if there is at least 1 file before I submit the whole form that the user is filling.

If i use the myDropzone.length it will still count the removed files from the dropzone so if the user adds 2 files and then removes one of them the .length would be = 2 and in that case I would need to know the real length which would be 1 in this particular case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get count of selected files in dropzone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910240/get-count-of-selected-files-in-dropzone)

Answer (score 18):

Dropzone provide multiple function to get only accepted, rejected, queued or uploading files.

```
// To access only accepted files count (answer of question)
myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length


// To access all files count
myDropzone.files.length
// To access all rejected files count
myDropzone.getRejectedFiles().length
// To access all queued files count
myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length
// To access all uploading files count
myDropzone.getUploadingFiles().length
```

Get from document API [here](https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/methods)

Comment: I am trying to get a list of the files that are in the Dropzone. How do I access the list of files in the Dropzone?

Comment: @user1794918 Use `myDropzone.files`. Remove `.lenght` of upper example and you can get file list of every sections

Answer (score 4):

"To access all files in the dropzone, use `myDropzone.files`."

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods

Comment: The problem is when the user decides to remove one of the files, then the .length remains the same counting the removed files, so I need to know how many files are there without the removed ones